# Getting Null Response while using OkHttp to hit an API

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am trying to hit an API using OkHttp since Volley won't let put the body data in multipart, if it could then I don't know how to do, so when I'm using this everything works the data is being sent, but I am constantly getting my response as null or ZERO . I tried hit the API using Postman it works perfect and then I put the same data static is my code and then run it ,still the same response.

The data is put using JSONobject

```
@SuppressLint( "StaticFieldLeak" )
public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask < RequestItem, String, String > {
    
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(RequestItem... params) {
        JSONObject object;
        RequestItem requestItem = params[ 0 ];
        JSONObject data = requestItem.object;
        Toast.makeText( AddHW.this, "dta"+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show( );
        Log.d( "data", "data" + data );
        //MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse( "text/plain" );
        object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put( "school_id", data.getInt( "school_id" ) );
            object.put( "batch_id", data.getInt( "batch_id" ) );
            object.put( "category", data.getInt( "category" ) );
            object.put( "subject", data.getString( "subject" ) );
            object.put( "due_date", data.getString( "due_date" ) );
            object.put( "repeat", data.getInt( "repeat" ) );
            object.put( "priority", data.getInt( "priority" ) );
            object.put( "description", data.getString( "description" ) );
            object.put( "additional_detail", data.getString( "additional_details" ) );
            object.put( "file_url", data.getString( "file_url" ) );
            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse( "application/json; charset=utf-8" );
            RequestBody json = RequestBody.create( object.toString(), JSON );
            Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
            builder.url( requestItem.url )
                .method( "POST", body )
                    .post( json );
                .addHeader( "Cookie", "__cfduid=d5209babc31d5f41904fce0f542568e4e1591610891" );
            Request request = builder.build();
            
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall( request ).execute();
                return Objects.requireNonNull( response.body() ).string();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d( "AddHW ", "error:" + e.getMessage() );
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute( s );
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject( s );
            if ( object.getString( "status" ).equals( "OK" ) ) {
                
                JSONObject res = object.getJSONObject( "results" );
                Toast.makeText( AddHW.this, "" + res.getString( "message" ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show( );
                Log.d( "addHw", "response: " + res.getString( "message" ) );
                show_add_homeWork( );
            }
            
        } catch ( JSONException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace( );
            Log.d( "error", "error:" + e.getMessage( ) );
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help You solve your issue ,

I noticed that you have used the `.method( "POST", body )` and I couldn't find any body may be due to insufficient code shown or may be it is a global variable or something , but  I see you creating a Requestbody from the object (JSONobject) in which i think you are storing your data from the user ( I hope so), and putting it in the `.post(json)`, which should work and you should get the Response you are looking for.

One more thing I don't think you should use the

> .addHeader( "Cookie", "__cfduid=d5209babc31d5f41904fce0f542568e4e1591610891" )

since this is kinda unnecessary and might be interfering with your backend.
Hope this answers your question .